# How to get the searchcount() total of matches into a lua variable

Tags: neovim, lua

The searchcount() gives use something like:

```
{'exact_match': 1, 'current' : 1, 'incomplete': 0, 'maxcount': 99, 'total': 5}
```

It is a dictionary, I am trying to do something based on the help:

```
    local result = vim.fn.searchcount(#{recompute = 1})
    print(result.total)
```

It gives: **E5113: Error while calling lua chunk: Vim:E715: Dictionary needed**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Lua, the `#` operator will return the length of a Lua table, the index of the largest element. In this case, `{recompute = 1}` doesn't have numbered elements, so `#{recompute = 1}` actually returns 0. (In any case, it will always return an integer number.) You might be mixing up Lua syntax with Vimscript syntax here, since `#{...}` is valid Vimscript syntax to define a Dictionary.

Just dropping the `#` should make your example work here.

```lua
local result = vim.fn.searchcount({recompute = 1})
print(result.total)
```

Comment: I have found a reference about a patch and also got some tricks from here: https://vi.stackexchange.com/posts/26304/revisions